# Bash Shell In Pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, bash, eclipse-plugin, pydev

How do I have the bash shell running with pydev?

I have resources that autoload when bash runs and I would like to be able to access them when I run a program in pydev.

Is there anyway to do this?

My current code would be able to access the resources if I ran the program from the terminal however I generally write / debug in an ide.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some info on the resources you access when you're in a bash shell which you can't when you're in PyDev?

Comment: .bash_profile exports

Comment: If you want to access the exports, can't you just start Eclipse from your bash shell? (that way it should start with those exports in place as it'll inherit that environment)

Comment: I was hoping for a setting / install within eclipse. I was under the impression that it was possible

Comment: You can configure that in eclipse (either by interpreter in the 'python interpreter preferences' or by launch in the run > run configurations), but they won't be kept updated with your bash file (i.e.: you'll have to remember to update both). Note that this mostly due to how the OS works (i.e.: a shell inherits the environment of the parent)